# Simple Parent/Child query

Tags: sql

I need to return a names of categories/sub-categories, and the recursion will only go 1 level deep (never more than 1 sub category)

Table Data would be something along the lines of:

```
CATEGORY NAME - CAT ID  - PARENT ID
Cat A         -    1    -    0
Cat B         -    2    -    0
Sub Cat A     -    3    -    1

DESIRED RESULTS
Cat A
Cat A > Sub Cat A
Cat B
```

Thanks!

EDIT: (here's what I tried so far)

```
SELECT FC1.CATEGORY_ID,
       FC1.CATEGORY_NAME,
       FC1.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID,
       FC2.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID,
       FC2.CATEGORY_NAME AS PARENT_CATEGORY_NAME
  FROM CATEGORY FC1
  LEFT
  JOIN CATEGORY FC2
    ON FC2.CATEGORY_ID = FC1.CATEGORY_ID
 ORDER BY CATEGORY_NAME
```

Comment: How many levels? Only 2?

Comment: SELECT FC1.CATEGORY_ID, FC1.CATEGORY_NAME, FC1.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID, FC2.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID, FC2.CATEGORY_NAME AS PARENT_CATEGORY_NAME FROM CATEGORY FC1 LEFT JOIN CATEGORY FC2 ON FC2.CATEGORY_ID = FC1.CATEGORY_ID ORDER BY CATEGORY_NAME

Comment: Post it in the question, not in a comment please.

Comment: Yes, I only need the Parent category names, and then Parent > Child names.. all returned within one result set.  Do I may need to do some type of derived table maybe?  I know I've done this (or something like this) beofre but I just can't recall how I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
    ON FC2.CATEGORY_ID = FC1.CATEGORY_ID
```

(joining each record to itself) to this:

```
    ON FC2.CATEGORY_ID = FC1.PARENT_CATEGORY_ID
```

(joining each record to its parent).